# Why double brackets in if {{ }} in Javascript if work?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Rewriting legacy code I've stumbled upon this intresting piece (*not actual code, just logic representation):

```
if (1===1) {{
   console.info(1)
}}
```

Why double `{` on opening and closing actually is working?

Comment: it's just a block within another block. a block is just a normal statement, modulo nesting. there's no reason this should not work.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Might be also a object literal - depending on line terminator placement.

Comment: @lexicore Not with just that line. Object literals need an `id` for a property or they'll throw an error, e.g. `prop: console.info(1)`

Comment: Even a (single) property/value pair does not make an object literal. For instance, `{ foo: "bar" }` will be parsed as a statement block containing a label (`foo:`) and a string literal (`"bar"`). On the other hand, applying an operator (such as `!`) or parentheses `({})` will force the parser to interpret the tokens as an object literal.

Comment: @blgt You are right, `{{console.info(1)}}` is not dangerous but something like `{+{}}` might be due to ASI.

Comment: @closers This is a valid and actually well-posed question on the JavaScript syntax. It is NOT a typo or similar as you suggest in the closing reason.

Comment: Maybe it's fundamental language design which I just don't know, but I've never seen it in any solution or documentation. Could you link me to some docs about it and solutions using it?

Comment: @Ultra Javascript uses [C-style syntax for code blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28programming%29#Syntax). It's generally fairly straightforward, just beware (as the previous comments hint at) typos that are hard to detect or newlines with automatic semicolon insertion

Comment: @blgt yeah but what uses does it have? `()` in JS have few uses like wrapping self-executable function or arytmetic grouping.

Answer (score 2):

If you format your code using any code formatting tool, it would format it like this

```
if (1 === 1) {
    {
        console.info(1)
    }
}
```

So, it just introduces a new block within the if-block. Since JavaScript doesn't have any block level scoping as of now, this construct will be of no use to us.

Comment: Any usages of this than?